# NotifyDataSetChanged function does not work on my recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I would to filter a recyclerview through searchview but i get a problem on the notifyDataSetChanged in the adapter.

In my fragment i set the adapter on the recyclerview in the OnCreateView

```
mAdapter = new EventsAdapter(getContext(), events);
eventRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

then i populate my recyclerview through firebase and i call the

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

to update the recyclerview

All right the list is showed correctly.

I call the OnQueryTextChange on the searchview

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            //Toast.makeText(getContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ciao", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String query = s.toLowerCase();
            newList.clear();
            for(Event event: events){
                String name = event.getEventName().toLowerCase();
                if(name.contains(query)){
                    newList.add(event);
                }
            }
            mAdapter.setFilter(newList);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

and there's the function setFilter in the adapter

```
public void setFilter(List<Event> filteredwordlist) {
    oldList.clear();
    oldList.addAll(filteredwordlist);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The problem is nothing happen, the recyclerview do not update

Why?!?

Thank you all for your answers

**EDIT**

**EventsFragment.java**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_events, container, false);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) v.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getComponent();
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    eventRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    eventRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    eventRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new HidingScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onHide() {
            hideViews();
        }
        @Override
        public void onShow() {
            showViews();
        }
    });

    /*Event e1 = new Event("la figa", "EventoPosto1", "Indirizzo", "mal", "21/01/12", "asaSAsas", "ASSAS", "CIAOCIA");
    Event e2 = new Event("ciao", "EventoPosto1", "Indirizzo", "mal", "21/01/12", "asaSAsas", "ASSAS", "CIAOCIA");
    Event e3 = new Event("la vacca", "EventoPosto1", "Indirizzo", "mal", "21/01/12", "asaSAsas", "ASSAS", "CIAOCIA");



    events.add(e1);
    events.add(e2);
    events.add(e3);*/ //TODO ESCLUSO PROBLEMA FIREBASE

    mAdapter = new EventsAdapter(getContext(), events);
    eventRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    firebaseFirestore.collection("events").orderBy("time").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {//todo .limit(numero limite)
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                List<DocumentSnapshot> temp = task.getResult().getDocuments();
                for(int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++){
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.ITALY);
                    SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("dd\nMMMM", Locale.ITALY);
                    Date d = null;
                    try {
                        d = sdf.parse(temp.get(i).get("time").toString());
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String formattedTime = output.format(d);
                    events.add(new Event(temp.get(i).get("event_name").toString(),
                            temp.get(i).get("event_place").toString(),
                            temp.get(i).get("place").toString(),
                            temp.get(i).get("location").toString(),
                            formattedTime,
                            temp.get(i).get("small_pic").toString(),
                            temp.get(i).get("cover_pic").toString(),
                            temp.get(i).get("description").toString()));
                }
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_events_toolbar, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search)
            .getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
    searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            //mAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            String query = s.toLowerCase();
            newList.clear();
            for(Event event: events){
                String name = event.getEventName().toLowerCase();
                if(name.contains(query)){
                    newList.add(event);
                }
            }
            mAdapter.setFilter(newList);
            return true;
        }
    });

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

**EventsAdapter.java**

```
public class EventsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EventsAdapter.EventsViewHolder>{
private List<Event> mEvents = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Event> eventListFiltered = new ArrayList<>();
private Context mContext;
private View v;
private ImageView placeBack, nameDateBack;
private TextView eventNameEditText, eventLocationEditText, eventDateEditText;
private ImageView eventImageView;
private List<Event> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Event> oldList = new ArrayList<>();

public EventsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Event> events) {
    mContext = context;
    mEvents = events;
    oldList = events;
    eventListFiltered = events;
}

@Override
public EventsAdapter.EventsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cell_event, parent, false);
    return new EventsViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(EventsAdapter.EventsViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bindEvents(eventListFiltered.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return eventListFiltered.size();
}

public class EventsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public EventsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        placeBack = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.place_back);
        nameDateBack = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_data_back);
        eventNameEditText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_event);
        eventLocationEditText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.place_event);
        eventDateEditText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_event);
        eventImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.event_background);
        mContext = itemView.getContext();
    }

    public void bindEvents(Event event) {
        eventNameEditText.setText(event.getEventName());
        eventLocationEditText.setText(event.getEventPlace());
        eventDateEditText.setText(event.getEventDate());
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(event.getEventCover()).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round).error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .into(eventImageView, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {

                    }
                });
    }
}





public void setFilter(List<Event> filteredwordlist) {
    filteredList.clear();
    filteredList.addAll(filteredwordlist);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Comment: in `setFilter()` add this  `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: The method setFilter() is in the adapter

Comment: have look [this](https://www.learn2crack.com/2017/03/searchview-with-recyclerview.html)

Comment: Have you logged the data you get to see if the data on query change is indeed different?

Comment: Yes i logged the data, and they are correct in the oldList

Comment: I meant to ask if you're sure if `oldData` and `newData` have different data.

Comment: Yes, the `oldList.addAll(filteredwordlist);` set the right filteredList

Comment: @zzan is `events` assigned to `oldList` in your `constructor`? please show code of your `EventsAdapter`.

Comment: nope, oldList is simply an empty List of event, I declare and inizialized it in this way `private List<Event> oldList = new ArrayList<>();` under the `public class EventsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EventsAdapter.EventsViewHolder>{`

Comment: The oldList is correct, i can see it in the debug, the only problem is that the `notifyDataSetChanged` does not work :/

Comment: @zzan Post your adapter class code and also code from the class where you are setting the adapter

Comment: I posted it in the question, because the code was too long for comment

Comment: Thank you for your help @Pulak

Comment: I suggest you add a log statement after the line `newList.add(event);` to know when and if the names are getting added to the `newList`. You can also check the size of `newList` in logs before calling `setFilter()`. Try to debug this way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this :

```
 public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ciao", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String query = s.toLowerCase();
        newList.clear();
        for(Event event: events){
            String name = event.getEventName().toLowerCase();
            if(name.contains(query)){
                newList.add(event);
            }
        }
        mAdapter.setFilter(newList);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
    }
```

and

```
 public void setFilter(List<Event> filteredwordlist) {
    oldList.clear();
    oldList.addAll(filteredwordlist);

 }
```